# formatting an odata reponse to return json

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to parse a reponse I get back from an API that returns data in the odata format.

The data contains all the data I need in an array(value), but I can't figure out how to get at that data and remove the root/parent element that holds it.

I'm returning this data to a javascript MVC frontend, so I need it to be in JSON format, but without it's parent.

The code I have just returns the whole odata object.

I don't need the parent part that says, ""odata.metadata":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/$metadata#Keys":

Here is the odata returned by the API:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/$metadata#Keys","value":[
    {
      "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('111')","Id":"111","Name":"VideoSearch","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":true
    },{
      "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('222')","Id":"222","Name":"DesktopRecorder","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":false
    },{
      "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('333')","Id":"333","Name":"Manage","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":false
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code that handles the api and odata:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://systech.edu/som_a/api/V1/Keys");
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "xxxx", "xxxx");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
```

desired JSON output:

```
{
  "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('111')","Id":"111","Name":"VideoSearch","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":true
},{
  "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('222')","Id":"222","Name":"DesktopRecorder","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":false
},{
  "odata.id":"http://systech.edu/SOM_a/Api/v1/Keys('333')","Id":"333","Name":"Manage","Timeout":20160,"IsDefault":false,"Auth":false,"err":false,"exclude":true,"Internal":true,"view":false
}
```

Comment: try this  var ODataJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json); ODataJSON.Property("odata.metadata").Remove();

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
var ODataJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json); ODataJSON.Property("odata.metadata").Remove();
```

Comment: that worked, but I wonder if there's a way to remove the array that encloses the elements.  I've edited the original question to include the desired output.  Thanks

Comment: its an array of same type objects, why do you want to remove it. Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do on the client side. The reason for it to be array is you are returning a collection of objects

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get a collection of objects that I could then use a model to represent each of those objects. So in javascript, something like 'myCollection.each(function (model) { ...do stuff... }